# Difficulty in deploying my MERN app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-redux, mern, heroku-cli

I am not able to deploy my app on Heroku and I am getting the following error every same time I try to push my code to Heroku.

First, I created my Heroku app using the command `heroku create`. Then I added and committed all the modified files to the git staging area and finally when I tried to push to Heroku using git it failed in the post-build part.

Command that I am using for pushing my code: `git push heroku master`

Error that I am getting:

```
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running heroku-postbuild
remote:        
remote:        > dev-community-starter@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_d493d086
remote:        > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_d493d086/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > core-js@3.8.1 postinstall /tmp/build_d493d086/client/node_modules/core-js
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > core-js-pure@3.8.1 postinstall /tmp/build_d493d086/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
remote:        > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_d493d086/client/node_modules/ejs
remote:        > node ./postinstall.js
remote:        
remote:        added 1937 packages from 730 contributors and audited 1942 packages in 48.194s
remote:        
remote:        123 packages are looking for funding
remote:          run `npm fund` for details
remote:        
remote:        found 5928 vulnerabilities (209 moderate, 5719 high)
remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
remote:        
remote:        > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_d493d086/client
remote:        > react-scripts build
remote:        
remote:        Creating an optimized production build...
remote: Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
remote: npx browserslist@latest --update-db
remote: 
remote: Why you should do it regularly:
remote: https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#browsers-data-updating
remote:        Failed to compile.
remote:        
remote:        ./src/utils/api.js
remote:        Cannot find module: 'axios'. Make sure this package is installed.
remote:        
remote:        You can install this package by running: yarn add axios.
remote:        
remote:        
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.DNuM9/_logs/2021-06-24T11_06_31_565Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! dev-community-starter@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the dev-community-starter@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.DNuM9/_logs/2021-06-24T11_06_31_594Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: b76c1f2afa5b943b747dc113ff0dc1004c044030
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version b76c1f2afa5b943b747dc113ff0dc1004c044030
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to intense-reef-14591.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/intense-reef-14591.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/intense-reef-14591.git'
```

Can anyone please guide me as to how to solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

I asume you already checked the following problems right?

```
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
```

You can also try not to include the `node_modules` folder in the push.

Also try to push it trough heroku web and a github repo

Comment: Yes I saw these and tried to debug also, but no luck still the error persists

Comment: Since the module that is giving you problems is 'axios', maybe you added it as a Dev dependency in the 'package.json'  file?

Comment: Yes, that is giving an issue. How can I solve it?

Comment: With the info I have I can only tell you to run a 'npm i axios' and then 'npm i' to make sure every package is installed

Answer (score 1):

According to the error logs, the `axios` package is not installed as a dependency in your `package.json`.

It may be possible that you have installed Axios globally on your device hence it will be working locally but during the Heroku deploy, it's unable to find that dependency.

So install it by running the command:

```sh
npm install axios
```

and try again. If the same problem persists then sharee your `package.json` file.